# How can I cover my wall furnace to prevent the summer heat coming through from the roof?

Tags: furnace

I live on the top floor of an older apartment building- I can feel the heat coming from the roof through my wall furnace (pilot light is off).

Comment: Radiant barrier is the best way I have found in attics it is like a thick foil that reflects the heat. Being an apartment this may be an issue an exhaust fan may be more likely for the landlord if they will do anything.

Comment: aluminum foil will stop what you feel without touching, which could be a lot or even most of it.